# Estimator API, Training Data is unbalance split among workers. Chief may finish first

Tags: tensorflow

I am using `tf.Estimator.train_and_evaluate` with `ParameterServerStrategy` distribute strategy in tensorflow 1.11.0. According to the log, distributor coordinator is running in INDEPENDENT_WORKER mode.

[image]

I split the whole training data(tfrecords) into multiple partitions, and each training worker (including the chief) has one partition. The problem is when the data is not balanced among workers, tensorflow behaves not as I expected. I draw to show the problem.

[image]

when using the `train_and_eval`, training stop conditions are: 1) max_step arrived 2) dataset reaches the end; evaluator stop condition is: global_step get from checkpoint >= TrainSpec.max_step. In a multi-worker distributed training, how to set `max_step` correctly?

code:

```
train_distribute = ParameterServerStrategy(num_gpus_per_worker=FLAGS.gpu_per_worker)
eval_distribute = MirroredStrategy(num_gpus_per_worker=FLAGS.gpu_per_worker,
                                   cross_tower_ops=cross_tower_ops_lib.AllReduceCrossTowerOps())
run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(
    model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir,
    save_checkpoints_secs=FLAGS.checkpoint_secs,
    save_summary_steps=FLAGS.summary_steps,
    keep_checkpoint_max=FLAGS.max_checkpoints,
    train_distribute=train_distribute,
    eval_distribute=eval_distribute)

estimator, train_spec, eval_spec = create_estimator_and_specs(run_config=run_config)
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

TF_CONFIG in each node:

```
chief node:
 {u'cluster': {
   u'ps': [u'ps:12615'], 
   u'chief': [u'chief:20396'], 
   u'worker': [u'worker1:18339', u'worker2:11609'], 
   u'evaluator': [u'evaluator:24352']}, 
   u'task': {u'index': 0, u'type': u'chief'}
 }

 woker 0:
 {u'cluster': {
   u'ps': [u'ps:12615'], 
   u'chief': [u'chief:20396'], 
   u'worker': [u'worker1:18339', u'worker2:11609'], 
   u'evaluator': [u'evaluator:24352']}, 
   u'task': {u'index': 0, u'type': u'worker'}
 }

 worker 1:
 {u'cluster': {
   u'ps': [u'ps:12615'], 
   u'chief': [u'chief:20396'], 
   u'worker': [u'worker1:18339', u'worker2:11609'],
   u'evaluator': [u'evaluator:24352']}, 
   u'task': {u'index': 1, u'type': u'worker'}
 }

evaluator:
{u'cluster': {
  u'ps': [u'ps:12615'], 
  u'chief': [u'chief:20396'], 
  u'worker': [u'worker1:18339', u'worker2:11609'],
  u'evaluator': [u'evaluator:24352']}, 
  u'task': {u'index': 0, u'type': u'evaluator'}
}
```